# How to handle white space in XML headers?

Tags: sql-server, xml

SQL Server 2012.  Given the following XML:

```
<header>
    <subheader>
        <Problems>
            <RAW VALUE="1" Sublot="abc"/>
            <RAW VALUE="2" Sublot="def"/>
            <RAW VALUE="3" Sublot="ghi"/>
        </Problems>
    </subheader>
</header>
```

how does one parse the XML in SQL Server?  I an having problems dealing with "RAW VALUE" as a name, such that

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@docHandle, '/header/subheader/Problems', 1)
WITH (
    'RAW VALUE' VARCHAR (100)
);
```

is invalid because of the quote around 'RAW VALUE'.  Brackets don't work either.  Is there a way to support the space in "RAW VALUE"?

Comment: `OPENXML` should be avoided as it's a common source of resource leakage - people regularly forget to call `sp_xml_removedocument` after finishing with the document handle. It doesn't help that Microsoft document examples also commonly neglect that. Prefer to use the [`nodes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type), [`query()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/query-method-xml-data-type) and [`value()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type) methods instead.

Comment: I'm calling sp_xml_removedocument already.  Do you have any information to my actual question?

Comment: As per the [Specifying ColPattern for mapping between columns and the XML attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openxml-transact-sql#b-specifying-colpattern-for-mapping-between-columns-and-the-xml-attributes) documentation... `[RAW VALUE] varchar(100) 'RAW[1]/@VALUE'`

Comment: It seems that you have a misconception with XML naming. In your case there is an **element** `<Problems>{...}</Problems>` and within several **self-closing elements** `<RAW />` all of which contain the same two **attributes** `VALUE="xyz"` and `Sublot="xyz"`. In this case it just *looks* like a *blank within the name*.

Answer (score 2):

The attributes of XML elements are accessed with the `@` XPath expression prefix, e.g.: `@VALUE` for the VALUE attribute, `@Sublot` for the Sublot attribute...

```sql
declare @example xml = N'<header>
  <subheader>
    <Problems>
      <RAW VALUE="1" Sublot="abc"/>
      <RAW VALUE="2" Sublot="def"/>
      <RAW VALUE="3" Sublot="ghi"/>
    </Problems>
  </subheader>
</header>';

select
  prob.raw.value('@VALUE', N'nvarchar(100)') as [Value],
  prob.raw.value('@Sublot', N'nvarchar(100)') as [Sublot]
from @example.nodes('/header/subheader/Problems/RAW') prob(raw);
```

Which yields the result:

| Value | Sublot |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | def |
| 3 | ghi |

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I don't have enough points to upvote, but I tried!